# self-joined model Comment that belongs to Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-join

I have two models. I want them behave like post with tree-structured comments.

Post:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

When I create a comment in console through

```
post = Post.create(title: 'Title', content: 'text')
comment = post.comments.create(content: 'text')
child = comment.children.create(content: 'text')
pp child
```

this is what I get:

```
[22] pry(main)> child = comment.children.create(content: 'text')
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<Comment:0x00007f16ec59cc20
  id: nil,
 content: "text",
 post_id: nil,
 parent_id: 5,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

I experimented a bit without much success and self-join guides did not help. What code is lacking in my models?

upd.

`child` is not saved into the database. Error: `["Post must exist"]`. But post exists. Post id is nit set when I run `comment.children.new(content: 'text')` How do I create an association like `children belongs_to :post, through: :parents` (pseudocode)

Comment: Your code is correct. What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is new comment with `post_id` of a parent comment. Not `nil`. I guess I need to set something in my Post, but I don't understand what exactly.

Comment: What is `comment` in `comment.children.new(content: 'text')`? Can you update the question with the code?

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention what post the parent comment belongs to.

`comment.children.new(content: "text", post: comment.post)`

Or you might also do this in a callback on your model.

in models/comment.rb

```
before_save :set_post_id

private

def set_post_id
  self.post_id = post.id || parent.post.id
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but i have all other field `nil`. Does not seem to be right.

Comment: other fields (id, created_at, updated_at) should be valued when the record is saved to the database successfully. but the logs you posted shows that the create call has been rolled back, check the `child.errors.full_messages` for more details.

Comment: Yes, did not realise it. Updated my question.

Comment: the belongs_to :post relationship is not optional so, you have to provide the post_id before you create the comment.